# When I parse DateTime should I also use localization?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app is running on `Seoul/ Korea`.

And I realized that when getting current time, I need to set local option.

so I use `timezone` package with below code.

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

final koreaTimeZone = tz.getLocation('Asia/Seoul');
  final koreaNow = tz.TZDateTime.now(koreaTimeZone);
  final formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(koreaNow);
  return formattedDate;
```

But I'm curious whether I should change all `parse` DateTime code of below codes with localization?

```
DateTime dateStringToDateTimeDot(String dateString) {
  return DateTime.parse(dateString.replaceAll('.', '-'));
}

String dateTimeToStringDiaryTimeLine(DateTime dateTime) {
  String diaryHour = dateTime.hour == 24
      ? "오전 0시"
      : dateTime.hour > 12
          ? "오후 ${dateTime.hour - 12}시"
          : "오전 ${dateTime.hour}시";

  String formattedDate =
      '${dateTime.month}/${dateTime.day} $diaryHour ${dateTime.minute}분';
  return formattedDate;
}

String dateTimeToStringDateLine(DateTime dateTime) {
  String formattedDate =
      '${dateTime.year}-${dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  return formattedDate;
}

String dateTimeToStringDateDot(DateTime dateTime) {
  String formattedDate =
      '${dateTime.year}. ${dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}. ${dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  return formattedDate;
}

String dateTimeToStringDateSlash(DateTime dateTime) {
  String formattedDate =
      '${dateTime.year}/${dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  return formattedDate;
}

String dateTimeToStringDateComment(DateTime dateTime) {
  String formattedDate =
      '${dateTime.year.toString().substring(2)}/${dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${dateTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${dateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  return formattedDate;
}

DateTime dbBirthdayToDateTime(String birthYear, String birthDay) {
  return DateTime.parse(
      "$birthYear-${birthDay.substring(0, 2)}-${birthDay.substring(2)}");
}
```

Comment: You should look in to the DateFormat class in the intl package.  You're doing a lot of this the hard way.